# Opensea-js What is the actual rate limit?

Tags: nft, ethereumj, opensea

I am wondering what is the actual rate limit of this api? Even with using an api key I get rate limited or throttled requests quiet fast. I can not find any resource about the actual rates they are limiting by in their docs, nor anywhere else.

Is someone on here with a knowledge about that?

What are the rate limits?
How do they rate limit? Counting requests from certain API keys? Do they track requests from the account wallet address thats included in the requests? IP based?

Cheers

Comment: definitely looking for the same thing. From your experience, from how many request/s you were blocked ?